Customer Uploads
New here & to Wordpress so not sure if this is achievable.
Soon I want customers to be able to upload their own images which I know I can do via a plug in.
However I really want to know if there’s anyway I can add/embed a template from Canva that they can add their images too that then uploads/adds to their purchase.
Hope that makes sense.
Thanks
I haven’t tried anything yet

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
